# How do I use the snap tool without having my objects intersect?

Tags: modeling, snapping

I'm a beginner blender user and I'm trying to do some of those famous shape such as donuts and I'm trying to make the shape of dripping icing, but when I use snap it intersects with the other part. How can I prevent this problem? Although most of the videos use it normally without any problems. I could make the donuts shape and I made the icing but I need to make the drip.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you don't completely understand what snapping does. Snapping basically makes moves you do in the editor (or outside of the editor) stepped. They snap to a grid. If you want to make those drips, I wouldn't try to pull the mesh down in edit mode because the geometry might not like it. I would extrude drips from faces on the icing mesh. Avoid the proportional editing for now cause it takes a lot of time to get used to and it's not really necessary in your case. And that tool is the reason for the intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find using closest edge or vertex is much easier to control than "snap to closest face". You can place your mouse cursor near the edge/vertex you want to snap to and an orange circle lets you know where it is about to snap to. If it is a complex model with lots of close together edges and vertices it helps to zoom in as much as possible to make selecting the correct snap point easier.

Also, selecting "closest", "center", "median" or "active" can yield dramatically different results depending on your geometry. Its not a bad idea to try each setting when you first use a new tool to see how each performs differently.

[image]

[image]